# Protect a sheet from opening within a workbook

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, password-protection, vba

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets. Is there any way to password protect users from even opening a sheet within the workbook? The sheet has a large graph on it that I don't want everyone to be able to see, let alone edit.

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT

I used the following code to allow users to click a formcontrol button to access the sheet in question.

```
Sub ShowHeatMap()
 Dim S As String
 S = InputBox("Enter Password")
 If S = vbNullString Then
     Exit Sub
 ElseIf S <> "wiretransfer" Then
     Exit Sub
 Else
     Worksheets("Training Heat Map").Visible = xlSheetVisible
 End If
End Sub
```

This is associated with my button on a kind of "homepage" sheet that I added to the workbook.

But I can't get the sheet to remain hidden when you open the workbook again. I tried this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Training Heat Map").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Any ideas? This code is inputted on the module for the sheet under general declarations

Comment: Do you mean you want some people to see the worksheet and some people to not see it, or no one to see it at all?

If you want no one to see it at all it may be better to just make the sheet very hidden, you can add VBA code that says Sheets("SheetName").Visible = xlVeryHidden

Comment: @clusks No I need some people to be able to see it :/

Comment: As an OT: Excel is not a viable software for security, if the user should not be allowed to see that data without a proper login, a software solution should be created for that purpose -and in that an export option to xls or something like it-; excel sheets/vba code protection can be broken within seconds.

Comment: Hi @sgdva, thank you for this information. The file is not important enough to require that sophisticated of a solution- and I am not qualified enough to implement one either. I will keep this in mind when presenting to my end user, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-to-password-protect-a-single-tab-in-a-workbook/934ceaeb-a6e8-400b-8123-0e2d393ff94b?auth=1), I think this might do the trick for you. Within VBA, put this within ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
MySheet = "Sheet1"
If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheet Then
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
    Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
        If Response = "MyPass" Then
            Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets(MySheet).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End If
Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
End Sub
```

Obviously will require a bit of tailoring to your needs. Remember that you will also need to password protect your VBA code, otherwise anyone will be able to view it and find out the password.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Btw: You can use `Sh` instead of `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: As for I didn't clarify so far: The problem is, that the `Workbook_SheetActivate`-event fires _after_ the sheet has been activated. So you can see all the data and then prompt for the password pops up. Also: the code worked (as in ran) after I deleted the line of variable declaration. I have no idea why that is.

Comment: Hey @clusks I tried this code and it didn't work for me, but I am trying another solution based on the link you provided. I am going to have a main sheet with formcontrol buttons that prompt an input box (where you enter the password) to view the sheet. However I can't get the code right to keep the sheet `xlveryhidden` each time you open the document. Can you refer to the edits in the original question and let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: @clusks never mind I figured out my mistake. Thanks for your answer, it works well for my needs.